# Laravel collection map function overrides default collection

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I have a code where I use map to create a new collection of high scores.
The problem I have is that it overrides the default user collections. Which is not my intention.

Here is the code

```
    $users = Users::all();
    $highscore = $users->map(
        function ($user) {
            $calls = $user->calls->filter(
                function ($call) {
                    $date = Carbon::parse($call->datetime)->format("Y-m-d");
                    $today = Carbon::now()->format("Y-m-d");
                    return $date == $today;
                }
            );
            return [
                'id' => $user->id,
                'duration' => $calls->sum('duration'),
            ];
        }
    );
```

If i dump the first user after getting all the users I get the first user. Like this.

```
$users = Users::all();
dd($users->first());
```

If I dump the first user after the high score map. I get all Calls from that user which is another model. Which means that the users collection has been modified. Like this.

```
$highscore = $users->map(
    function ($user) {
        $calls = $user->calls->filter(
            function ($call) {
                $date = Carbon::parse($call->datetime)->format("Y-m-d");
                $today = Carbon::now()->format("Y-m-d");
                return $date == $today;
            }
        );
        return [
            'id' => $user->id,
            'duration' => $calls->sum('duration'),
        ];
    }
);
dd($users->first()):
```

Any idea on how to handle this behaviour?

Comment: In both your examples `$user` is not defined in the scope you are trying to access `$user->first()`. Also the filtering is best done via a database query instead of via a filter on all results

Comment: I don't see any way to reproduce your results.  The only reason you'd see that is if you were modifying $user within your closure since objects are passed by reference.

Comment: @apokryfos this was just a typo. Fixed it.

Comment: @Devon i'm thinking that the $calls = $user->calls->filter() method is actually overriding the array so it sets the calls as the first item in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

The map function returns an array of [[$userId => $duration], ...]. What you want to do is to order your users by the sum of their calls.

I believe that, in order to do that easily, you should add to your User model:

```
public function getTodayCallSum() {
    return $user->calls->filter(function($call) {
        $date = Carbon::parse($call->datetime)->format("Y-m-d");
        $today = Carbon::now()->format("Y-m-d");
        return $date == $today;
    })->sum('duration');
}
```

And then edit your query:

```
$users = User::all();
$firstUser = $users->sortBy('todayCallSum')->first();
```

I haven't tested this code, but I think it should help you towards the right direction.